# What is meaning of s2+=s1.charAt(i) in the programs

Tags: java

I have this programs

```
String s1="java";
String s2="";

for (int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    s2+=s1.charAt(i); // Please explain this line.  
}
System.out.println("The Reversal of "+s1+" is "+s2);
```

What exactly happens in the code marked in the bold.

Comment: you have written that in your last statement ... 'reversal'. It is starting from last character in given string and coming backwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets walk through the code:

Assign `s1` to the `String` "java" and assign `s2` to the `String` "".

```
String s1="java";
String s2="";
```

Loop from `i = s1.length() - 1` to `i >= 0` *downwards*.

```
for (int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
    s2+=s1.charAt(i);
}
```

Lets go through this:

**Iteration 1**, `i = s1.length() - 1 = 3`, the code becomes:

```
s2 += s1.charAt(3);
```

What does this mean? Well, `+=` is a compound concatenation operator, so lets replace it:

```
s2 = s2 + s1.chartAt(3);
```

`charAt(n)` gives the nth character of a `String`, zero indexed - lets replace that too:

```
s2 = s2 + "a"
```

So, we take `s2` which is "" and concat it with "a", we assign the result *back* to `s2`.

**Iteration 2**, `i = 2`, the code becomes:

```
s2 += s1.charAt(2);
```

Now, we know that `s1.charAt(2)` is "v" and `s2` is "a" so:

```
s2 = "a" + "v" = "av"
```

**Iteration 3**, `i = 1`, the code becomes:

```
s2 += s1.charAt(1);
```

Now, we know that `s1.charAt(1)` is "a" and `s2` is "av" so:

```
s2 = "av" + "a" = "ava"
```

**Iteration 4**, `i = 0`, the code becomes:

```
s2 += s1.charAt(0);
```

Now, we know that `s1.charAt(0)` is "j" and `s2` is "ava" so:

```
s2 = "ava" + "j" = "avaj"
```

And the loop terminates since `i <= 0`.

So what does the line `s2+=s1.charAt(i)` do? It takes the `i`th character (zero indexed) of `s1` and *appends it* to `s2`.

It should be noted that this code can be written much more efficiently as:

```
String s1 = "java";
String s2 = new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString();
```

This has two advantages:

It is much shorter and more readable.

It is much *faster*, the concatenation operator on a `String` must:

1. create a new `char[]` of size `left.length + right.length`
2. copy the original `String`'s contents into the `char[]`
3. copy the rhs contents into the `char[]`
   4  return the `char[]` wrapped in a `new String`

This is **very expensive** - to add a single character to a `String` the *entire original `String`* must be copied over. This is because `String` is **immutable**.

Don't believe me - read [this excellent article](http://kaioa.com/node/59). Then never use `String +=` in a loop again.

Comment: String s2 = new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString(); - note that this implementation is sub-optimal.

Comment: @dzidzitop is it? How?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for step-by-step process. It cleared up my confusion. Also, the link is good.

Comment: Additional copying is performed when constructing StringBuilder(), which is unnecessary. Instead, an empty string builder should be created and then populated in the reverse order. However, this implementation is far better than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
s2+=s1.charAt(i); // adding ith index char in s1 to current value of s2
```

Eg:

```
 String s1="123456";
 String s2="";
   for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
       s2+=s1.charAt(i);
       System.out.println(s2);
  }
```

By running this

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

You can see how `s2` adding

Answer (score 0):

the `s2+=s1.charAt(i)` means take s2 and add the value of char at index i of string s2.

Answer (score 0):

The string s1 is appended reversed to the string s2 refers to in a *very* inefficient way.

Answer (score 0):

it means s2=s2+s1.charAt(i).for example, in the first loop,it means s2=""+"a" so s2="a".

Answer (score 0):

+= is Addition assignment.

a += b; is the same with a = a + b;
In case of Strings, the + means concatenation.

s1.charAt(i) returns the char from position i in the s1 String. Therefore,

```
 s2+=s1.charAt(i);
```

concatenates the ith char from s1 to the current s2 String.

Answer (score 0):

The code marked in **bold** appends each character obtained from the variable `s1`  to the variable `s2` in reverse order.